# Can not find any wifi networks list in Ubuntu Mate

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, ubuntu-mate, raspberrypi

I just installed Ubuntu LTS 64-bit on RPi4. Then I connected wifi with (with yaml config file edited)

```
sudo netplan apply
```

After that I updated and upgraded software and then installed ubuntu-mate-desktop. Then when I open a browser I can use internet. But I am unable to find any networks in the wifi panel applet. In fact there is nothing there. But I can use internet. If I have to search for a wifi network and connect with it I have to again reconfigure yaml in /etc/netplan folder and connect. How to get a gui for this?